# Sending mail from local apache server fails, no error message given

Tags: php, apache, smtp, xampp

Foreword; I've looked through a lot of topics, done what they said, but nothing works for me - so I made this one.

So I'm using xampp/apache to send mail from a php file, but all I get is "Message delivery failed...".

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or maybe how to display an error of whats going wrong because I don't get any errors.

Here is my code..
(I censored my email and pass for obvious reasons)

```
if (!mail("censored@gmail.com", "title", "blahblahblah", "From: me@hotmail.com")) {
die("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>") . mysqli_error();
}
?>
```

sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
auth_username=censored@gmail.com
auth_password=censored
```

php.ini:

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**If any additional information is requested it will be from beyond this point.**

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing less secure apps to send you email using this link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Use some kind of liblary, for example, `php_libmail` for sending mail via SMTP.

Comment: I'd agree with @Priler - use a library. I usually use PHPMailer

Comment: @mikekaperys ok so I'm trying phpmailer. But I keep getting "Sorry, nothing to display ..." as the only thing that appears on my screen.
Any idea whats up with that? I've paster the phpmailer folder into my htdocs. I'm referencing the require("../PHPMailer/_lib/phpmailer-fe.php");

Answer (score 0):

SElinux blocks sendmail from web server by default, change settings in SElinux as:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```